# How to get an ESPN developer key?

Tags: api, espn

I searched http://espn.go.com/apis/devcenter/ but couldn't find anywhere that you can create your API key. I also created an account with ESPN but no luck.

Answer (score 9):

It's not public 4 months ago (http://espn.go.com/static/apis/devcenter/blog/read/publicretirement.html)

Dear ESPN API Developers,

Since the launch of the ESPN Developer Center in March 2012 the capabilities and direction of our API program have continued to evolve in order to serve sports fans in the best way possible.

As part of that evolution, we have made the difficult decision to discontinue our public APIs, which will enable us to better align engineering resources with the growing demand to develop core ESPN products on our API platform.

Effective today, we will no longer be issuing public API keys. Developers utilizing the ESPN API with a public API key may continue to do so until Monday, December 8, 2014, at which point the keys will no longer be active.

We want to thank all of you for supporting the ESPN API, and we hope you found value interacting with the service over the past two years.

The ESPN API Team